# What kind of command is TRUNCATE in SQL ANSI

Tags: sql

in SQL ANSI Truncate is a function or a statement ?

What kind of command is TRUNCATE in SQL ANSI ?

Comment: so the question is that I need to know what is written in SQL ANSI abou TRUNCATE

Comment: Based on a search of the SQL92, 1999 and 2003 standards documents: the TRUNCATE keyword is not part of the ISO SQL Standard. Note: ISO is the body that originates and controls the SQL Standard; ANSI is/was one of the national bodies that publishes the standard.

Answer (score 2):

It's a statement, specifically a data manipulation ([DML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language)) statement, like `DELETE` or `INSERT`. It's basically `DELETE FROM` with no `WHERE`, except most engines handle logging the command differently from `DELETE FROM`.

Comment: do you have idea if it is what say SQL ANSI ?

Comment: @user2464581: I don't know what you mean by "what say SQL ANSI". If you mean, is it part of ANSI SQL, [Wikipedia says yes, but only recently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncate_(SQL)). It's widely-supported, though, I know it exists in SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, and Postgres for instance.

Comment: I mean if this is what is written in the ansi sql.
in DB2 TRUNCATE can be a command and a function, you can truncate a date or a decimal number in a single row or TRUNCATE a table excluding all rows.

Comment: so the question is that I need to know what is written in SQL ANSI abou TRUNCATE

Comment: @user2464581: I don't know if ANSI SQL *also* has a `TRUNCATE` function. But even if it does, it wouldn't be a problem, because it's trivial to tell whether you're using the statement or function in any given SQL.

Comment: @user2464581: *"so the question is that I need to know what is written in SQL ANSI abou TRUNCATE"* Well, if only there were some document you could refer to... Oh, wait. (I believe you have to pay for it.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about ANSI SQL, but in Microsoft SQL Server, **TRUNCATE** is a statement.